# How to configure clickable links in SMS?

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink, sms, clickable

Many mobile operating systems (such as Android and iOS) automatically hyperlink URLs and Phone Numbers included in an SMS. Is this behavior managed by the mobile carrier, the OS, or the Device?

I'm designing an application that requires users be able to access a WAP site via a hyperlink in an SMS. Unfortunately, this site has to be accessible to both smartphones *and* feature phones.

Any information on general standards or in-market statistics would be great!

Answer (score 2):

> Is this behavior managed by the mobile carrier, the OS, or the Device?

On Android, it is "managed" by whoever wrote the SMS client app. That could be anyone. Any SMS client worth its salt should be making URLs clickable, but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to check WAP PUSH, which make URL clickable in all phones (expect the Iphone O think). Check this guide on how to format a WAP PUSH http://nexmo.com/documentation/how-to/send-a-wap-push-message/

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely dictated by the application.  In fact other applications such as the browser, etc perform the same operation on telephone numbers, addresses, etc.  Just make sure you format your text in a manner that looks like a link or whatever it is.  For example

Phone number: (xxx) xxx-xxx or xxxxxxxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx, etc.
Hyperlink: http://xxxxxx.xxx

(BTW SO does it as well...I never inserted the link ;-) )

etc.